# Akka Cluster aware Router unable to find routees

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

A small example is pasted here: http://lpaste.net/94385

I want to be able to start a main Dispatcher machine as the seed node for my cluster. The Dispatcher has a cluster aware router directed at the workers of the cluster. I want to be able to then start worker machines as needed and have the dispatching router automatically be made aware of their existence so that it can begin sending work to them.

The issue is that if I start the Dispatcher machine first (as it's the seed node), the cluster aware router is started and cannot find any of its routees (fair enough, they haven't been started yet). The docs mention this:

```
The routee actors should be started as early as possible when starting the
actor system, because the router will try to use them as soon as the member
status is changed to 'Up'. If it is not available at that point it will be
removed from the router and it will only re-try when the cluster members are changed.
```

When I start a new worker machine I can see that it has joined the cluster, but any messages sent to my router are forwarded to deadletters. I'm not completely clear on the advice from the docs because starting new workers should change the cluster members, but still the router is not made aware of them no matter how many new workers I create.

If I start a worker node first, then dispatcher, the messages are received by the worker just fine.

To summarize: I want a cluster aware router that can be started on the first seed node in a cluster. Any new nodes that contain routees of the router should be made available to the router when they join the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get your example to work by changing the configuration to be as follows:

```
/clusterDispatcher/clusterRouter {
  router = adaptive
  metrics-selector = mix
  cluster {
    enabled = on
    routees-path = "/user/clusterWorker"
    allow-local-routees = off
  }
}
```

The only change I made was to set allow-local-routees = off. By default, it's on, which means messages will also be routed to the same node that holds the router. But this won't work in your example since you didn't create a clusterWorker on the dispatcher node.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using a grouped cluster aware router. Take a look at [pooled cluster aware routers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/cluster-usage.html#Router_with_Pool_of_Remote_Deployed_Routees). Where a grouped router expects routees to already exist on the remote nodes, a pooled router creates them on nodes with specified roles, so it's okay if the target node comes up before the router.

We use pooled cluster aware routers to manage pools of worker nodes. For an example and some friendly pointers, take a look at [this post](http://blog.goconspire.com/post/64780988287/akka-at-conspire-part-4-dont-fall-into-our) from our engineer Ryan Tanner (specifically, see the "Don’t Split Superversion Across Your Cluster" header).

The [whole series](http://blog.goconspire.com/post/64130417462/akka-at-conspire-part-1-how-we-built-our-backend-on) of posts from Ryan is meant to share some of our early learning about Akka and especially clustering. Hope it's helpful!